# How to limit the number of INSERT records with Populator in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table I am trying to fill to eventually create a pretty network diagram. One of the tables is called User and the other is called relationships. I'd like to fill them out with about 10 entries each. The relationship is one user to many relationships.

The model I am using is

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150603200530) do

  create_table "relationships", force: true do |t|
    t.integer "source"
    t.integer "target"
    t.integer "value"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string  "name"
    t.integer "group"
  end

end
```

I am using the populate gem. It is very cool

The relationship table is related to the user table as relationship.source=user.id. I would like to generate randome values for 'source', 'target' and 'value' of between 1 and 10.
in a file called populate.rake (in lib/assets) so far I have:

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Erase and fill database"
  task :populate => :environment do
    require 'populator'
    require 'faker'

    [User, Relationship].each(&:delete_all)

    User.populate 100 do |user|
      user.name = Populator.words(1..3).titleize
      Relationship.populate 1..10 do |relationship|
        relationship.source = 1..10
        relationship.target = 1..10
        relationship.value = 1..10
      end
  end
  end
  end
```

but I get the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: too many terms in compound SELECT: INSERT INTO "relationships" ("id", "source", "target", "value") VALUES (1, 9, 10, 6).... etc.
```

Comment: This gem might help you https://github.com/stympy/faker

Comment: Not really flexible enough but thanks

Comment: @usmanali - I find `ffaker` slightly more robust.

Comment: If `relationship.source=user.id`, why are you using populate for `source`?  It would probably help to see your models.  Cool gem btw.

Comment: I removed relationship.source. I got no errors but relationship.source is nil for all records.

Comment: I guess you should set it to user.id?

Comment: OK so it turns out this message is a bit misleading as it means I have generated too many records not too many fields. I reduced to User.populate 20 do |user| and it works fine. Anyone know how to take the lid off this. Is there a max records settting or something I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error seems to come from SQLite which has a limit of how many records you can insert with one `INSERT` statement.

You can try to reduce the number of records per INSERT by setting the populator option `:per_query`:

```
User.populate(100, :per_query => 10)
```

Comment: Yep. That was it. You just beat me to it. Cheers